# Attempt to present UIViewController on ViewController which is already presenting UIAlertController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I just new to swift iOS programming. I write some code. Just simple, i want to perform an alert and then move to another view controller via "performSegueWithIdentifier". But i got this output:

**"Warning: Attempt to present UIViewController: 0x7fa05b72dd60  on Kilaundry.ViewController: 0x7fa05b49a2c0 which is already presenting UIAlertController: 0x7fa05d859d70 "**

I think the warning is after this code: "NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock".

Why I can't perform an alert and then move to another view controller via "performSegueWithIdentifier"? Please help me to find why this warning happen.

Here it is my codes :

```
                        if let data = data, let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                            print(jsonResult)

                            Resp_code = jsonResult["Resp_code"] as? String;
                            Resp_message = jsonResult["Resp_message"] as? String;

                            if Resp_code == "01" {
                                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Information", message:Resp_message!, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
                                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
                                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginSucceed", sender: self)
                                }
                            } else {

                                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"It seems "+Resp_message!, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
                                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Why are you using NSOperation queue? I think you want to use dipatch_get_main_queue() if you want to use it on the main thread. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving this error because you are attempting to present a modal view controller on a view controller that is already showing a modal VC - you present an alert controller, and then immediately trigger a segue (which is presumably also a modal).
A view controller can only have one presenting view controller at a given time. The easiest way of doing what you want is to present the 'OK' alert on the VC that is presented by the "LoginSucceeded" segue.

However, I would reconsider whether you should be showing the alert at all.  I suggest you read the [official Apple guidelines on the use of alerts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Alerts.html) - which basically say 'don't show an alert unless you really need to'. In particular, don't show alerts to inform users that the app is functioning normally.
Showing the error alert when your request fails is correct - showing one when the user logs in successfully is not necessary.